# DropDown Swift 3 compile error

Tags: swift3, cocoapods, alamofire

I upgraded my Podfile to us

```
target 'MyApp'
      pod 'DropDown'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = "3.0"
        end
    end
end
```

When I try to compile, I get Swift3 compile errors with the DropDown pod. But their page says they support Swift3 natively. https://github.com/AssistoLab/DropDown

I am attempting to use Edit > Convert, I still get errors. Why is this happening? Same issue with AlamoFire. I updated to the latest version by removing the version requirement from the Podfile, removed Pods directory, pod install, updated my swift version to 3.0 in the target settings and I'm getting compile errors.

Comment: Rather than removing the version requirement, I would suggest explicitly defining a version that is Swift-3 compatible. It could be that your pods repo is out of date, so it's picking up older versions of the pods.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think to update my pods repo, I'll try that, thank you!

Comment: Let us know how it goes.

Comment: Strangely, the original project still had failure. But after updating my pods repo I created an ew project and it installed ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than removing the version requirement, I would suggest explicitly defining a version that is Swift-3 compatible. It could be that your pods repo is out of date, so it's picking up older versions of the pods.